# Facebook API - Adding a friend via embedded device wrapper

Tags: java, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

We have a new project, building a fully featured facebook App on an embedded device (using Java) as a part of a new home automation system.

All is going well however we have hit a road block when it comes to adding friends. Our interface is a complete wrapper over the facebook UI (i.e. no browser). The only way I know how to add a friend is by sending a request to `http://www.facebook.com/addfriend.php?id=XXXX`

From here, the user is prompted to add a friend. The question is how should be go about wrapping up this request (i.e. mirroring it) so the user needs to click accept or deny and then forward this request off to Facebook?

AFAIK there is no API for adding friends... How can we go about mimicking this form and sending the request without having to implement a full browser? Space is also an issue so some clunky framework to try an emulate a browser window popup isnt going to work for us.

Any ideas and tips would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to fake such a request without breaking Facebook's CSRF protections, and if you did that the loophole would likely be closed almost immediately. If your app has an embedded browser there's a Friends dialog you can use to send friend requests, and accept existing friend requests, but it won't be trivial to simulate user logins and interactions with the dialog for security reasons

Comment: This is what we were thinking in the worst case. Guess leaving this feature out isnt a deal breaker. Could you give me any more info on the Friends Dialog (i.e guessing this would be a popup based on the url in my question)?

Comment: The docs are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/ - if you 'send' a request from user A to user B, where user B has already sent user A a friend request, the dialog serves as an 'accept request' dialog rather than a 'send request' dialog